# Generic solution update to sort multiple columns and filter a cut.off

Tags: r, sorting, filter, dplyr, output

hy, Here is an update proposal for the solution presented by [@Sam Dickson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34160745/ordering-multiple-columns-using-cut-off-values-in-r).
Who can contribute to creating an output closer to the [Expected output] and using the dplyr function to generalize the solution.

```
data.frame(
  RC1=c(0.902,0.9,0.899,0.825,0.802,0.745,0.744,0.74,0.382,0.356,0.309,0.295,0.194,0.162,0.162,0.156,0.153,0.147,0.144,0.142,0.123,0.113,0.098,0.062),
  RC2=c(0.206,0.282,0.133,0.057,0.091,0.243,-0.068,0.105,0.143,0.173,0.329,0.683,0.253,0.896,-0.155,-0.126,0.06,-0.158,0.952,0.932,-0.077,-0.062,0.322,-0.065),
  RC3=c(0.153,-0.029,0.093,0.138,0.289,0.071,0.413,-0.011,-0.069,0.181,0.123,-0.035,0.807,0.104,-0.044,0.504,0.15,-0.004,-0.013,0.106,0.785,-0.053,0.751,0.858),
  RC4=c(0.078,0.05,0.219,0.216,0.218,0.114,0.122,0.249,0.726,0.108,0.725,-0.089,0.249,0.146,0.622,-0.189,0.099,0.406,0.05,0.026,-0.018,-0.095,0.007,-0.118),
  RC5=c(0.217,0.021,-0.058,0.166,0.352,0.09,0.26,-0.354,0.065,-0.014,0.064,0.359,0.134,-0.114,0.212,0.178,0.878,0.71,-0.019,-0.021,0.015,-0.055,0.165,-0.074),
  RC6=c(0.027,-0.007,0.087,0.104,0.045,0.319,0.296,0.205,0.088,0.816,0.229,0.302,0.163,0.059,-0.256,0.604,-0.07,0.394,-0.02,-0.041,0.071,-0.008,0.219,-0.068),
  RC7=c(-0.015,-0.15,0.073,0.126,0.06,0.347,0.082,-0.093,-0.155,0.093,-0.045,-0.175,-0.021,0.004,0.052,-0.184,-0.054,-0.008,0.012,-0.004,0.094,0.951,-0.001,-0.118))->df 
row.names(df)<- c("X5","X12","X13","X2","X6","X4","X3","X11","X15","X10","X16","X8","X20","X19","X17","X21","X9","X7","X22","X24","X1","X14","X23","X18")

  ord1 <- apply(as.matrix(df),1,function(x) min(which(abs(x)>=0.4),ncol(df)))
  ord2 <- df[cbind(1:nrow(df),ord1)]
  df[order(ord1,-abs(ord2)),] 
  df1<-df[ , ]> 0.4
  row.names(df1)<- c("X5","X12","X13","X2","X6","X4","X3","X11","X15","X10","X16","X8","X20","X19","X17","X21","X9","X7","X22","X24","X1","X14","X23","X18")
  df1
  
  df[df[,]< 0.4] <- ""
  df

Output:
      RC1   RC2   RC3   RC4   RC5   RC6   RC7
X5  0.902                                    
X12   0.9                                    
X13 0.899                                    
X2  0.825                                    
X6  0.802                                    
X4  0.745                                    
X3  0.744       0.413                        
X11  0.74                                    
X15                   0.726                  
X10                               0.816      
X16                   0.725                  
X8        0.683                              
X20             0.807                        
X19       0.896                              
X17                   0.622                  
X21             0.504             0.604      
X9                          0.878            
X7                    0.406  0.71            
X22       0.952                              
X24       0.932                              
X1              0.785                        
X14                                     0.951
X23             0.751                        
X18             0.858
```

Expected output:

[image]

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: For Q1, what do you mean by "sort the columns from largest to smallest, in each column"? Do you mean you want to sort the columns - which column is first, which column is second, etc.? Or do you mean you want to sort the rows, keeping the columns in the same order, RC1 first, RC2 second, etc.?

Comment: Your image seems to have the rows sorted. And your code already has `dplyr::arrange(-RC1)`. which will sort the rows based on the `RC1` values in descending order. Your image shows the RC1 values in *mostly* descending order, but then there are weird things like row `X14` having a `RC1` value much higher than the ones around it. Maybe you want to sort by the sum of the rows? Or something else?

Comment: And what defines the highlighted cells in your output? Is it everything above some cut-off highlighted? Or are the top 10% of values highlighted? Or something else?

Comment: And lastly, what do you want the output to be in? Are you producing a table in RMarkdown, for HTML? Or Word? or PDF? Or an image?

Comment: @phuycke, What do you have so far? R: The output I'm showing. Even so, the %>% dplyr::arrange(-RC1,-RC2,-RC3,-RC4,-RC5,-RC6,-RC7) function only arranged column RC1. It was the maximum I could reach.

Comment: @GregorThomas, You mean you want to sort the rows, keeping the columns in the same order, RC1 first, RC2 second, etc.? Exactly.

Comment: `arrange(-RC1,-RC2, -RC3, ...)` says "sort the data frame rows in descending order by columm `RC1`. If there are ties in `RC1`, then use `RC2` as a tiebreaker. If there are ties in RC1 and RC2, then use RC3 as a tiebreaker... Your data frame doesn't have duplicated values, so it is meaningless to sort by more than one column.

Comment: Maybe you want to sort by the sum of the lines, or something else? No. The other question: Your image appears to have the lines sorted. And your code already has dplyr :: organize (-RC1). which will sort the rows based on the RC1 values ​​in descending order. Your screenshot shows the RC1 values ​​mostly in descending order, but there are weird things like the X14 line with a much higher RC1 value than those around it. Exactly, but the value 0.413 is a value that belongs to the interval established in the RC3 column.

Comment: Please fix your data, it is not reproducible and you should ask only one question per post.

Comment: And what defines the highlighted cells in your output, is it all above some highlighted cut? Yes, view my Question 2: How to hide the values ​​in each column when the value is =< 0.04?

Comment: @RonakShah, fixed data.

Comment: @GregorThomas, And finally, how do you want the output to be? Are you producing a table in RMarkdown, for HTML? Or Word? or PDF? Or an image? R: In this case it could be an image or RMarkdown, whichever is easier.

Comment: @GregorThomas, arrange(-RC1,-RC2, -RC3, ...) says "sort the data frame rows in descending order by columm RC1. If there are ties in RC1, then use RC2 as a tiebreaker. If there are ties in RC1 and RC2, then use RC3 as a tiebreaker... Your data frame doesn't have duplicated values, so it is meaningless to sort by more than one column. R:  For the problem I am addressing, the ordering following this pattern is important to help interpret the table.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to understand the order you want. You have code that produces an ordering. But you also ask for help with the ordering. You say you want ordering like the image, but you do not explain the logic for that ordering. In the image, the first 10 rows are `RC1` values in descending order, but then in row 11 (X16) the RC1 value increases from .142 to .162, and then the next row is even higher!  Why are the `X16` row and especially the `X8` row below the `X15` and `X10` rows? Explain the reasoning and we can help copy it. If you can't explain it, there is little we can do to help.

Comment: @GregorThomas, Looking for that solution, for something similar,  Sam Dickson "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34160745/ordering-multiple-columns-using-cut-off-values-in-r". Solved the first issue of this problem, but it wasn't using dplry. I think this can help you understand the issue better. Very grateful for your availability. How do I see only values ​​upper 0.4 in each column, and if possible highlight in bold or add a background?

Comment: OH I SEE! The sorting only applies to values > 0.4. You should have talked about the >0.4 threshold in Q1. Are these EFA loadings? If so, you can probably use the `parameters` package, something like `library(parameters); your_efa %>% model_parameters(sort = TRUE, threshold = 0.4)` to produce a table much like what you want.

Comment: @GregorThomas, Fixed the problem presented, I think it is now clearer.

Comment: @GregorThomas, Corrected the title and thanks for the exchange of knowledge. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now the question is cleared up, I think this does what you want:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(across(everything(),
        ~ ifelse(. < 0.4, "", format(., digits = 3)))) %>%
  arrange(across(everything(), desc))
#      RC1    RC2    RC3    RC4    RC5    RC6    RC7
# 1  0.902                                          
# 2  0.900                                          
# 3  0.899                                          
# 4  0.825                                          
# 5  0.802                                          
# 6  0.745                                          
# 7  0.744         0.413                            
# 8  0.740                                          
# 9         0.952                                   
# 10        0.932                                   
# 11        0.896                                   
# 12        0.683                                   
# 13               0.858                            
# 14               0.807                            
# 15               0.785                            
# 16               0.751                            
# 17               0.504                0.604       
# 18                      0.726                     
# 19                      0.725                     
# 20                      0.622                     
# 21                      0.406  0.710              
# 22                             0.878              
# 23                                    0.816       
# 24                                           0.951
```

Answer (score -1):

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <-
  data.frame(
  id=c("X5","X12","X13","X2","X6", "X4","X3","X11","X15","X10","X16","X8","X20","X19","X17","X21","X9","X7","X22","X24","X1","X14","X23","X18"),
  RC1=c(0.902,0.9,0.899,0.825,0.802,0.745,0.744,0.74,0.382,0.356,0.309,0.295,0.194,0.162,0.162,0.156,0.153,0.147,0.144,0.142,0.123,0.113,0.098,0.062),
  RC2=c(0.206,0.282,0.133,0.057,0.091,0.243,-0.068,0.105,0.143,0.173,0.329,0.683,0.253,0.896,-0.155,-0.126,0.06,-0.158,0.952,0.932,-0.077,-0.062,0.322,-0.065),
  RC3=c(0.153,-0.029,0.093,0.138,0.289,0.071,0.413,-0.011,-0.069,0.181,0.123,-0.035,0.807,0.104,-0.044,0.504,0.15,-0.004,-0.013,0.106,0.785,-0.053,0.751,0.858),
  RC4=c(0.078,0.05,0.219,0.216,0.218,0.114,0.122,0.249,0.726,0.108,0.725,-0.089,0.249,0.146,0.622,-0.189,0.099,0.406,0.05,0.026,-0.018,-0.095,0.007,-0.118),
  RC5=c(0.217,0.021,-0.058,0.166,0.352,0.09,0.26,-0.354,0.065,-0.014,0.064,0.359,0.134,-0.114,0.212,0.178,0.878,0.71,-0.019,-0.021,0.015,-0.055,0.165,-0.074),
  RC6=c(0.027,-0.007,0.087,0.104,0.045,0.319,0.296,0.205,0.088,0.816,0.229,0.302,0.163,0.059,-0.256,0.604,-0.07,0.394,-0.02,-0.041,0.071,-0.008,0.219,-0.068),
  RC7=c(-0.015,-0.15,0.073,0.126,0.06,0.347,0.082,-0.093,-0.155,0.093,-0.045,-0.175,-0.021,0.004,0.052,-0.184,-0.054,-0.008,0.012,-0.004,0.094,0.951,-0.001,-0.118)
)

# Question 1: How to sort the columns, from largest to smallest, in each column, as in the image?
data %>% arrange(-RC1)
#>     id   RC1    RC2    RC3    RC4    RC5    RC6    RC7
#> 1   X5 0.902  0.206  0.153  0.078  0.217  0.027 -0.015
#> 2  X12 0.900  0.282 -0.029  0.050  0.021 -0.007 -0.150
#> 3  X13 0.899  0.133  0.093  0.219 -0.058  0.087  0.073
#> 4   X2 0.825  0.057  0.138  0.216  0.166  0.104  0.126
#> 5   X6 0.802  0.091  0.289  0.218  0.352  0.045  0.060
#> 6   X4 0.745  0.243  0.071  0.114  0.090  0.319  0.347
#> 7   X3 0.744 -0.068  0.413  0.122  0.260  0.296  0.082
#> 8  X11 0.740  0.105 -0.011  0.249 -0.354  0.205 -0.093
#> 9  X15 0.382  0.143 -0.069  0.726  0.065  0.088 -0.155
#> 10 X10 0.356  0.173  0.181  0.108 -0.014  0.816  0.093
#> 11 X16 0.309  0.329  0.123  0.725  0.064  0.229 -0.045
#> 12  X8 0.295  0.683 -0.035 -0.089  0.359  0.302 -0.175
#> 13 X20 0.194  0.253  0.807  0.249  0.134  0.163 -0.021
#> 14 X19 0.162  0.896  0.104  0.146 -0.114  0.059  0.004
#> 15 X17 0.162 -0.155 -0.044  0.622  0.212 -0.256  0.052
#> 16 X21 0.156 -0.126  0.504 -0.189  0.178  0.604 -0.184
#> 17  X9 0.153  0.060  0.150  0.099  0.878 -0.070 -0.054
#> 18  X7 0.147 -0.158 -0.004  0.406  0.710  0.394 -0.008
#> 19 X22 0.144  0.952 -0.013  0.050 -0.019 -0.020  0.012
#> 20 X24 0.142  0.932  0.106  0.026 -0.021 -0.041 -0.004
#> 21  X1 0.123 -0.077  0.785 -0.018  0.015  0.071  0.094
#> 22 X14 0.113 -0.062 -0.053 -0.095 -0.055 -0.008  0.951
#> 23 X23 0.098  0.322  0.751  0.007  0.165  0.219 -0.001
#> 24 X18 0.062 -0.065  0.858 -0.118 -0.074 -0.068 -0.118

# Question 2: How to hide the values ​in each column when the value is =< 0.04?
data %>% filter(RC1 > 0.04)
#>     id   RC1    RC2    RC3    RC4    RC5    RC6    RC7
#> 1   X5 0.902  0.206  0.153  0.078  0.217  0.027 -0.015
#> 2  X12 0.900  0.282 -0.029  0.050  0.021 -0.007 -0.150
#> 3  X13 0.899  0.133  0.093  0.219 -0.058  0.087  0.073
#> 4   X2 0.825  0.057  0.138  0.216  0.166  0.104  0.126
#> 5   X6 0.802  0.091  0.289  0.218  0.352  0.045  0.060
#> 6   X4 0.745  0.243  0.071  0.114  0.090  0.319  0.347
#> 7   X3 0.744 -0.068  0.413  0.122  0.260  0.296  0.082
#> 8  X11 0.740  0.105 -0.011  0.249 -0.354  0.205 -0.093
#> 9  X15 0.382  0.143 -0.069  0.726  0.065  0.088 -0.155
#> 10 X10 0.356  0.173  0.181  0.108 -0.014  0.816  0.093
#> 11 X16 0.309  0.329  0.123  0.725  0.064  0.229 -0.045
#> 12  X8 0.295  0.683 -0.035 -0.089  0.359  0.302 -0.175
#> 13 X20 0.194  0.253  0.807  0.249  0.134  0.163 -0.021
#> 14 X19 0.162  0.896  0.104  0.146 -0.114  0.059  0.004
#> 15 X17 0.162 -0.155 -0.044  0.622  0.212 -0.256  0.052
#> 16 X21 0.156 -0.126  0.504 -0.189  0.178  0.604 -0.184
#> 17  X9 0.153  0.060  0.150  0.099  0.878 -0.070 -0.054
#> 18  X7 0.147 -0.158 -0.004  0.406  0.710  0.394 -0.008
#> 19 X22 0.144  0.952 -0.013  0.050 -0.019 -0.020  0.012
#> 20 X24 0.142  0.932  0.106  0.026 -0.021 -0.041 -0.004
#> 21  X1 0.123 -0.077  0.785 -0.018  0.015  0.071  0.094
#> 22 X14 0.113 -0.062 -0.053 -0.095 -0.055 -0.008  0.951
#> 23 X23 0.098  0.322  0.751  0.007  0.165  0.219 -0.001
#> 24 X18 0.062 -0.065  0.858 -0.118 -0.074 -0.068 -0.118


# Question 3:That the solution is, if possible, generic for n columns
data %>% filter_at(vars(starts_with("RC")), ~ .x > 0.04)
#>   id   RC1   RC2   RC3   RC4   RC5   RC6   RC7
#> 1 X2 0.825 0.057 0.138 0.216 0.166 0.104 0.126
#> 2 X6 0.802 0.091 0.289 0.218 0.352 0.045 0.060
#> 3 X4 0.745 0.243 0.071 0.114 0.090 0.319 0.347

# Question 4: If possible, how visually can the doR output be presented in table format (expected output)?.
# Output is already a table, you can use kable package for HTML table rendering
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: OP's question is pretty unclear, but this doesn't come close to their desired output. And filtering whole rows out seems very different than "hiding values". I'd strongly suggest asking the OP to clarify what they want before posting answers that have only a tiny chance of being correct.

Comment: @GregorThomas, I need the output of r to be as similar as possible to the example table. The issues to be considered are presented in the problem. I am clarifying possible doubts. Thanks for contributions to make the matter clearer. The answer presented does not answer the problem properly.

Comment: @danlooo, The answer presented does not answer the problem properly. See that in line RC1, for example, the values ​​between RC2 are not corrected in the correct order as in the example table.